# Usage of Scala mutable Set to transform Spark DataFrame fails on cluster, how to replace it with a Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have such a dataframe:

```scala
val similarityJoinResult = toBeMatched1
      .similarityJoin(toBeMatched2, "name", 0.6)
      .select(
        $"datasetA.directorId",
        $"datasetB.companyId",
        $"distance",
      )
```

Function `similarityJoin` behaves as a common `inner join`, but matches elements based on some similarity. Column `distance` is a estimation of similarity, the lower this value, the more similar are names.
Thus, it creates a lot of matches. For example, on our all data this DF has 10kk rows while there are only 10k unique director IDs. It is necessary to remove duplications and select best matches.

I designed an algorithm for this task:

1. Sort DF by `distance` in the ascending order.
2. Go row-by-row and evaluate a boolean flag.
3. If company ID OR director ID were already met in previous rows with this flag being true, set flag to false for this row. Otherwise, set flag to true.
4. Drop all rows with this flag being false.

Here is a sample code I wrote for this algorithm:

```scala
def selectRowsWithUniqueIds(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val col1Ids: mutable.Set[String] = mutable.Set()
  val col2Ids: mutable.Set[String] = mutable.Set()

  def processRow(row: Row): (String, String, Boolean) = {
    val id1 = row.getString(0)
    val id2 = row.getString(1)
    // add ids to set and take this row only if both ids are never seen before
    val takeRow = !(col1Ids.contains(id1) || col2Ids.contains(id2))

    if (takeRow) {
      col1Ids.add(id1)
      col2Ids.add(id2)
    }

    (id1, id2, takeRow)
  }

  df.map(processRow)
    .toDF(df.columns(0), df.columns(1), "takeRow")
    .filter($"takeRow")
    .drop("takeRow")
}

similarityJoinResult
  .orderBy($"distance".asc)
  .transform(selectRowsWithUniqueIds)
```

For this example DF:

```scala
val df = Seq(
    ("id1", "myId1", 1),
    ("id1", "myId2", 1),
    ("id1", "myId3", 1),
    ("id2", "myId1", 15),
    ("id2", "myId2", 4),
    ("id2", "myId3", 2),
    ("id3", "myId1", 16),
    ("id3", "myId2", 5),
    ("id3", "myId3", 3),
).toDF("directorId", "companyId", "distance")
```

the correct result is

```
+----------+---------+
|directorId|companyId|
+----------+---------+
|id1       |myId1    |
|id2       |myId3    |
|id3       |myId2    |
+----------+---------+
```

*Note*: using grouping by one ID column and then grouping by another one results in data loss, consider DF from the example.

But my solution does not work on cluster (works locally), it fails before starting due to class initialization error. I am assuming that this is because of Scala mutable.Set usage.

I have several questions regarding this issue:

1. I think that even if we do not have initialization error, the code still would not work as designed. I assume that Spark worker 1 would have its own ID sets, worker 2 - also its own ID sets, and so own, leading to preserving some duplications in general case. Is my assumption correct?
2. If answer on the first question is "yes", then will adding of `.coalesce(1)` help?
3. I am going to replace Scala sets with datasets/dataframes, how to update them dynamically and efficiently check that any particular value is not present in them?

Scala version is 2.12.17 and Spark is 3.3.2.

Comment: Can you solve the problem from another perspective? For example, as I saw, you need a row for each `Id`, so you can `window` over, `order by` the similarity factor, and take the first one. I think using a local watch variable (like the set you used) is not scalable.

Comment: @meysam, yep, we are going to use window, but unfortunately this leaves less results.
For the example DF from the question with `Window` approach the result contains pairs `(id1, myId1)` and `(id2, myId3)`, there is no pair for `id3`.

Comment: What's your `window` code?

Comment: The same as you shown in the answer you provided. We need one-to-one correspondence, so after window over `directorId`, window over `companyId` must be done, and this approach eliminates pair `id3, myId3`, since for `myId3` the best pair is `id2`. Solution with sets, however, tries to preserve as much pairs as possible. For `id3` the best pair is `myId3`, but for `myId3` the best pair is `id2`; in such case designed solution takes the seconds best pair for `id3` which is `myId2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the lowest distance for each `directorId`, something like this could help:

```scala
val df = Seq(
    ("id1", "myId1", 1),
    ("id1", "myId2", 1),
    ("id1", "myId3", 1),
    ("id2", "myId1", 15),
    ("id2", "myId2", 4),
    ("id2", "myId3", 2),
    ("id3", "myId1", 16),
    ("id3", "myId2", 5),
    ("id3", "myId3", 3),
).toDF("directorId", "companyId", "distance")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val ws = Window.partitionBy("directorId").orderBy("distance")
val df2 = df.withColumn("rank", row_number.over(ws)).filter("rank = 1").show(false)
```

and result for the given dataframe is like this:

```
+----------+---------+--------+----+
|directorId|companyId|distance|rank|
+----------+---------+--------+----+
|id1       |myId1    |1       |1   |
|id2       |myId3    |2       |1   |
|id3       |myId3    |3       |1   |
+----------+---------+--------+----+
```